# Is there a way to pass a conditional (service) parameter to a service in Angular 8?

Tags: angular

I have **Contacts.component** that uses **Contact.Service** to get all Contacts from a backend.

Contact.Service depends on **Contact.Client** or **AdminContact.Client** to return the right dataset.

There's also **Main.Service** that has a method with returns true is user is an Admin

```
public isAdmin(): boolean {
   return true; // might return false also.
}
```

I would like to know if there's a way to tell Contact.Service to receive the right client conditionally if the user is an admin or not.

I was exploring the useFactory method in @NgModule but I can't find a way to condition the dep: [...]

Comment: It sounds like your `Contact.Service` needs to have the `Main.Service`, `Contact.Client`, and `AdminContact.Client` as dependencies. The `Contact.Service` would need to use the `Main.Service` to determine which version of the client injected to use when getting the dataset.

Comment: @DanielWStrimpel it would imply that Contact.Service needs to detect if this or that client needs to be invoked using if/else statements.  Instead, I would like to pass a customer service parameter to Contact.Service from the component module having Contact.Service as dependency.

Comment: Would you expect each module using your `Contact.Service` to be aware of the logic to know which client to use?

Comment: Yes, Contact.Service needs that dynamic parameter, so any module using it need to provide that client parameter.

Comment: Somewhere you are going to have to have logic to use your `Main.Service` to figure out which client to use. In order to do this, the code will have to have the reference to the `Main.Service` and both clients to know which to pass into the `Contact.Service`. Why would are you hesitant to put that in the `Contact.Service`?